# Создание отдельных настроек Objective c

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Пытаюсь сделать через Navigation Controller приложение с добавлением новых кнопок с разными настройками, что бы в настройках вводить название и оно отображалось на главной странице. Но у меня получается, что все настройки дублируются. В приложении создаю кнопку (cell), нажимаю на нее, ввожу название в одном, он всем дает такое же название. И на главной не отображает название. Возможно ли, это сделать здесь или я не правильно делаю? Может, вообще, все по другом надо делать?

```
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController]; 
//Создаю кнопку в приложении

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    Event *newEvent = [[Event alloc] initWithContext:context];
    newEvent.timestamp = [NSDate date];
        
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
        abort();
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Event *event = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell withEvent:event];
    return cell;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
            
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
            abort();
        }
    }
}


- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell withEvent:(Event *)event {
    cell.textLabel.text = event.timestamp.description;
}


#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController<Event *> *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    
    NSFetchRequest<Event *> *fetchRequest = Event.fetchRequest;
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:NO];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
    
    NSFetchedResultsController<Event *> *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![aFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
        abort();
    }
    
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
            
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
            
        default:
            return;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
    
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
            
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
            
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] withEvent:anObject];
            break;
            
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] withEvent:anObject];
            [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:newIndexPath];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}


        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *nazvan = [defaults objectForKey:@"nazvan"];
    
    _myTextField.text = nazvan;

[_myTextField resignFirstResponder];
    NSString *nazvan = [_myTextField text];
// Сохраняю
```

Могу весь код скинуть.

Comment: Из приведенного отрывка кода проблема непонятна, добавьте код, чтобы ее можно было воспроизвести

Comment: Как скинуть? Пытался через Yandex.диск, но не загружает.

Comment: В вопрос добавьте код, по возможности убрав все лишнее

Comment: Добавил код создания страницы. Возможно здесь не правильно.